# Dynamics Field Service Mobile deep link not navigating to entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to navigate to a Field Service Mobile entity from a deep link as Microsoft indicate in his documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dynamics365/field-service/mobile-deeplink

I am using this:

```
<a href="fsmobile://open?jsbridge;msdyn_workorder;{work_order_id}">TEST</a>
```

It is opening the aplication in both Android and Windows OS, but only opens the app, not navigating to the entity.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

try this to use below .................

href="fsmobile://open?msdyn_workorder;{work_order_id}">TEST

fsmobile://open?msdyn_workorder;